# Django custom user cant use signals with custom User

Tags: django, django-signals, djoser

Have a look at my custom User and user profile

```
class Users(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=False, db_column='email')
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_column='is_staff')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_column='is_active')
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, db_column='date_joined')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False, db_column='updated_at')

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    objects = UsersManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'mn_users'
        verbose_name = 'user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'users'

class UserProfiles(models.Model):
    user_profile_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='user_profile_id')
    user_id = models.OneToOneField('Users', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='user_id')
    photo = CloudinaryField('image')
    msisdn = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True, blank=True, unique=True, db_column='msisdn')
    nationality_id = models.ForeignKey(Nationalities, related_name='nationalites2userprofiles', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, db_column='nationality_id')
    language_id = models.ForeignKey(Languages, related_name='preferred_languages2users', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, db_column='language_id')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, db_column='created_at')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False, db_column='updated_at')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.role_id

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'mn_user_profiles'
        verbose_name = 'user_profile'
        verbose_name_plural = 'user_profiles'
```

So I am using Django rest framework to create the user and this is working properly. Issue is I want a user Profile created when a user is created. For this i made a signals file in
users/signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from .models import Users, UserProfiles


@receiver(post_save, sender=Users)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfiles.objects.create(users=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Users)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

I then added the above to the users/app.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'users'


class UserProfileConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'UserProfiles'

    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

On my installed apps I call the users app as such

> 'users.apps.UsersConfig',

and I have declared my

> AUTH_USER_MODEL = "users.Users".

So what could be the issue here. It inserts the user just fine but doesn't create the user profile. I'm also using djoser with django rest framework

Comment: It is not clear to me why you make both a custom user model, and a userprofile model. Usually a custom user model is defined, exactly to *prevent* creating such profile: by creating a custom user model, one can move all the fields to that user model, and hence no profile model is necessary.

Comment: Well the custom user was done to disable use of username field and to replace this with email. User Profile is to store other user data like profile pic, locations etc

Comment: but I don't see much benefit here in making two models, if the user model can store this, it avoids extra queries, and complicated walks through the item.

Comment: okay I can move the functionalities to the user model but why does the signal not work that there is major question as I know ill need it somewhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the urls.py:

```
from .signals import *
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue You need to include the signal in the URLs.py file